# Ordering by last inserted row

Tags: cassandra

I have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "blog" (
        blog_id INT,
        post_id INT,
        body TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (blog_id,post_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_id DESC);
```

I want to get sorted list of blog_id by post_id , that means If I have `blog_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) sort them by post_id`

I think the best way is a materialized view , but I don't know how to implement it?

Comment: The above schema will give you list of `blog_id` with descending sorted `post_id`... what is your expected output...

Comment: I have some blog ids , like (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)  I want to sort them according to last record that means If blog 10 has a new record I blog 10 is top of list , I want to show a list of last blogs post